# How to calculate the depth of sorting networks?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation, sorting

I have trouble understanding how to calculate the depth of a sorting network on $n$ inputs.

For example, in case of selection sort, we have:

$\qquad \displaystyle D(n)=D(n-1)+2\\\qquad D(2)=1$

which leads to

$\qquad \displaystyle D(n)=2n-3=\Theta(n)$

I have confirmed that the depth of selection sort is equal to $2n-3$ by hand, but I can't understand how the recurrence $D(n)=D(n-1)+2$ is derived.

Comment: Welcome! I am confused as to what is being asked here. Are you asking how to read a recurrence, or why this recurrence applies to selection sort? Do you have a sorting network implementation of selection sort at hand, or are you talking about the algorithm and its recursion depth?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture of the selection-sort sorting network?  What does it look like?

Answer (score 2):

For selection/bubble sorting network algorithms, the main tricky point is that "**some operations are overlapped**" or in other words because of ***[pipeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28computing%29)***! (it is shown in figure below)
You can find more information in [these lecture notes](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Rolf_Karlsson/lect10.pdf) by Rolf Karlsson.

This is the reason why the time complexity is linear!
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure pipelining (as seen in processors?) is a good analogy here; it's more like perfect parallelism, isn't it?

Comment: @Raphael: I changed the picture which shows the pipeline concept better!